# Pre-load a staticly linked C symbol

Tags: c, preloading

Is it at all possible to pre-load a staticly linked symbol?

In linux, I can use

`LD_PRELOAD=libSomeLibrary.so ./anExecutableLinkedToAnOtherLibrary`

But this only works if the symbols are linked dynamically. Now I need to inject some symbols to an executable where the symbols are statically linked to some other library.

I know that in the general case, this is theoretically impossible, since the static symbols might even have been inlined. But if we have a debug build with no optimizations and full debug symbols included, it should in theory be possible to inject our symbols in the right places.

I'm interested in an answer in both the linux and windows worlds, but even just solving this in linux will suffice.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to load an object file/static library? You can always build an .so out of it.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this: I've an executable that calls some library functions and they are staticly linked. I want to somehow override those functions without re-compiling the executable.

Comment: What does it mean to statically link a function? Do you have a static library with these functions? If so, they are not linked at all, just stored in the library to be linked later.

Comment: Imagine that the "library" and the executable is compiled like this:
gcc myprogram.c library.c -o myprogram -O0 -g3 (so that's what I mean by staticly linked)
Now, I'd like to, somehow, change the behavior of the "myprogram" binary by somehow replacing a function in library.c

Comment: Aha I see. I'm not aware of any OS-supported way of doing this. You may want to look at the [DynInst API](http://www.dyninst.org/) that can patch executables in many different ways. Or you may try to do [something like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33340/Code-Injection-into-Running-Linux-Application).

Answer (score 2):

There is no preload mechanism for static symbols, because ld.so is not used for them. The operating system simply maps the file into memory and starts executing it.

You might be able to modify the binary to contain a new version of the library. One way would be to use `objcopy` to strip out the old symbols and then `ld` to link new ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. I've stripped out the symbols successfully (readelf -s doesn't show them) but re-linking doesn't work. I think the symbols aren't used internally.